# Null pointer exception when GestureOverlayView is empty

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, gesture

I have an activity in which the user will give a signature using GestureOverlayView. After providing the signature, the image will be saved in the internal memory of the application and a reference (image name) and other details will be included in a SQLite table.

Here is the **layout** file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#142c57"
    android:padding="3dp"
    tools:context=".SupplierCustomerDetailsSignatureActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3" >

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_blue" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/customer_name_textView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="TextView"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="22sp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/table"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_1"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="DD Details: "
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dd_details_textView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="DD No.: "
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dd_no_textView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Drawn On: "
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/drawn_on_textView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Amount: "
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/amount_textView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Type: "
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/type_textView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Date Time: "
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/date_time_textView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18sp" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/remarks_editText"
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/table"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/gradientbg"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Remarks"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
                    </EditText>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/receipient_name_editText"
                        android:layout_width="500dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/remarks_editText"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/gradientbg"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Recepient Name"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
                    </EditText>

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/acceptance_radioGroup"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/receipient_name_editText"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radio0"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:text="Accept"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radio1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Reject"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

            <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
                android:id="@+id/customer_sign_gestures"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:fadeEnabled="false"
                android:fadeOffset="5000000000"
                android:gestureColor="#000000"
                android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
                android:gestureStrokeWidth="3"
                android:uncertainGestureColor="#000000" />

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/customer_sign_gestures"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/save_button"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
                        android:text="Save"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
                        android:text="Clear"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the **activity**:

```
public class SupplierCustomerDetailsSignatureActivity extends Activity {

    TextView customer_name_textview;
    TextView dd_details_textview;
    TextView dd_no_textview;
    TextView drawn_on_textview;
    TextView amount_textview;
    TextView type_textview;
    TextView date_time_textview;

    GestureOverlayView customer_sign_gesture;

    Button cancel_btn;
    Button save_btn;

    String customersSelected;

    RelativeLayout headerLayout;
    TableRow tableRow1;
    TableRow tableRow2;
    TableRow tableRow3;
    TableRow tableRow4;
    TableRow tableRow5;

    EditText remarks_edittext;
    EditText receipient_name_edittext;

    RadioGroup accept_reject_radio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_supplier_customer_details_signature);
        // To remove focus from edittext
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        customer_name_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer_name_textView);
        dd_details_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dd_details_textView);
        dd_no_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dd_no_textView);
        drawn_on_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawn_on_textView);
        amount_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount_textView);
        type_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_textView);
        date_time_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_time_textView);
        customer_sign_gesture = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.customer_sign_gestures);
        headerLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_1);
        tableRow1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
        tableRow2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
        tableRow3 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);
        tableRow4 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow4);
        tableRow5 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow5);

        remarks_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.remarks_editText);
        receipient_name_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.receipient_name_editText);

        accept_reject_radio = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.acceptance_radioGroup);

        customersSelected = getFromPreference("customer_code_clicked");

        if (customersSelected.contains("#@~@#")) {
            headerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tableRow1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tableRow2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tableRow3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tableRow4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tableRow5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        customer_name_textview
                .setText(getFromPreference("customer_name_clicked"));
        dd_details_textview.setText("Lore Ipsum");
        dd_no_textview.setText("7894561230");
        drawn_on_textview.setText("State Bank of India");
        amount_textview.setText("Rs. 10,000");
        type_textview.setText("Cheque");

        // makeAToast(customersSelected);

        // setting current date
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
        String formattedDate = df3.format(c.getTime());
        date_time_textview.setText(formattedDate);

        cancel_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_button);
        cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                clearData();
            }
        });

        save_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                saveData();


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do something on back.
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                SupplierCustomerDetailsSignatureActivity.this,
                SupplierDetailsActivity.class);

        finish();
        SupplierCustomerDetailsSignatureActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }

    // method to clear data
    public void clearData() {
        customer_sign_gesture.cancelClearAnimation();
        customer_sign_gesture.clear(true);
    }

    // method to save and send data
    public void saveData() {

        createIfNotExistDraftToSend();


        //checking which radio button is checked
        int index = accept_reject_radio.indexOfChild(findViewById(accept_reject_radio.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
        String acceptReject;
        if (index ==0)
        {
            acceptReject ="accept";
        }
        else
        {
            acceptReject ="reject";
        }

        // checking whether edittext contains values
        if (remarks_edittext.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0
                && receipient_name_edittext.getText().toString().trim()
                        .length() > 0) {


            // checking whether there is multiple id
            if (customersSelected.contains("#@~@#")) {
                Log.i("Full String ", customersSelected);
                String assetClasses = customersSelected;
                String[] splits = assetClasses.split("#@~@#");
                for (int k = 1; k < splits.length; k++) {
                    Log.i("Values", splits[k]);

                    // getting image
                    Bitmap gestureImg = customer_sign_gesture.getGesture().toBitmap(100, 100,
                            8, Color.BLACK);

                    String image = saveImageToInternalSorage(gestureImg,splits[k], remarks_edittext.getText().toString(),
                            receipient_name_edittext.getText().toString(), acceptReject, date_time_textview.getText().toString());
                    Log.i("Image:", image);

                }
            } else {

            }

        } else {
            makeAToast("Please enter credentials!");
        }

    }

    // Internal storage
        private String saveImageToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String cl_doc_no, String remarks,
                String recepient,  String ar, String mobdttm) {
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
            // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            Random gen = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = gen.nextInt(n);
            String fotoname = "Photo-" + n + ".png";
            Log.i("Photo Name:", fotoname);
            // Create imageDir
            File mypath = new File(directory, fotoname);

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {

                fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

                // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to
                // the OutputStream
                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //inserting in local database
            insertDraftToSend(cl_doc_no, remarks,
                    recepient, fotoname, ar, mobdttm);
            //saveInPreference("Photo",fotoname);
            return directory.getAbsolutePath();
        }

    // ===============Local Database Handling Methods===================

    // method to create If Not Exist
    public void createIfNotExistDraftToSend() {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                SupplierCustomerDetailsSignatureActivity.this);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        db.createIfNotExistDraftToSend();
        db.close();
    }

    // method to insert data
    public void insertDraftToSend(String cl_doc_no, String remarks,
            String recepient, String signature, String ar, String mobdttm) {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                SupplierCustomerDetailsSignatureActivity.this);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // db.createDataBase();
        values.put("cl_doc_no", cl_doc_no);
        values.put("remarks", remarks);
        values.put("recepient", recepient);
        values.put("signature", signature);
        values.put("ar", ar);
        values.put("mobdttm", mobdttm);
        db.insertDraftToSend(cl_doc_no, remarks, recepient, signature, ar,
                mobdttm);
        db.close();

    }

    // ===============Local Database Handling Methods===================

    // method to save variable in preference
    public void saveInPreference(String name, String content) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(name, content);
        editor.commit();
    }

    // getting content from preferences
    public String getFromPreference(String variable_name) {
        String preference_return;
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        preference_return = preferences.getString(variable_name, "");

        return preference_return;
    }

    // method to show toast message
    public void makeAToast(String str) {
        // yet to implement
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }


}
```

**The problem which I am facing is that if the user is providing the signature then the desired data is getting inserted in the local database and everything is fine, but if the user is keeping the signature area blank, then the app is force closing due to null pointer exception. Please suggest me how to know whether the signature area or the GestureOverlayView is blank or not before inserting the data.**

Comment: Which line is the exception thrown at?

Comment: // getting image
                    Bitmap gestureImg = customer_sign_gesture.getGesture().toBitmap(100, 100,
                            8, Color.BLACK);  This is the line

Comment: Have you considered checking for null before calling toBitmap()?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to get the image:

```
customer_sign_gesture.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap gestureImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(customer_sign_gesture.getDrawingCache());
```

Comment: I know how to get the image, but the above code gives null pointer exception when there is no gesture drawn.

Comment: I mean, if you load the bitmap using the above method.. the exception won't be thrown.. solves your problem

Comment: But how to I know whether there is any drawing or not, as I have to also put a validation for that